# How to solve $\sum_{k=0}^{20} k\;\;^kP_k$

Tags: permutations, combinations

I can simplify this equation: $$\sum_{k=0}^{20} k*\:^kP_k$$ 
to something like $$1*1!\;+2*2!\;+\;...\;+\;20*20!$$
But how do I simplify this equation? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may observe that
$$
k \cdot k!=(k+1)!-k!
$$ then one may use a [telescoping sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html).